# Why does the file not transfer completely? Python Socket Programming

Tags: python, sockets

The problem I'm having is to get a file from the server. Lets say I want to 
"get ./testing.pdf" which sends the pdf from the server to the client. It sends but it is always missing bytes. Is there any problems with how I am sending the data. If so how can I fix it? I left out the code for my other functionalities since they are not used for this function.

server.py

```
import socket, os, subprocess          # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
#host = ''
port = 5000                # Reserve a port for your service.
bufsize = 4096
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.

while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print 'Got connection from', addr

    while True:
      userInput = c.recv(1024)


    .... CODE ABOUT OTHER FUNCTIONALITY

      elif userInput.split(" ")[0] == "get":
      print "inputed get"
      somefile = userInput.split(" ")[1]
      size = os.stat(somefile).st_size
      print size
      c.send(str(size))

      bytes = open(somefile).read()
      c.send(bytes)
      print c.recv(1024)

c.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket, os               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
#host = '192.168.0.18'
port = 5000                # Reserve a port for your service.
bufsize = 1

s.connect((host, port))

print s.recv(1024)
print "Welcome to the server :)"

while 1 < 2:
    userInput = raw_input()

   .... CODE ABOUT OTHER FUNCTIONALITY

    elif userInput.split(" ")[0] == "get":
        print "inputed get"
        s.send(userInput)
        fName = os.path.basename(userInput.split(" ")[1])
        myfile = open(fName, 'w')
        size = s.recv(1024)
        size = int(size)
        data = "" 

        while True:
            data += s.recv(bufsize)
            size -= bufsize
            if size < 0: break
            print 'writing file .... %d' % size

        myfile = open('Testing.pdf', 'w')
        myfile.write(data)
        myfile.close()
        s.send('success')

 s.close
```